# Resetting menu_order to 0 for posts in PHPmyAdmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin, menu-order

Installed [a plugin](http://www.nsp-code.com/premium-plugins/wordpress-plugins/advanced-post-types-order/) that allows the re-ordering of posts from any post type / category / tag using a drag/drop interface.

After some time of using, my post order went haywire and new posts began to appear in a jumbled order. The plugin's native *reset* button resolved this, but the old posts are still jumbled (only for two particular categories).

Plugin author suggested updating **menu_order** to 0 only for the post type in question and I have a few questions:

1. I can't seem to find the appropriate field, which table would I look in?
2. Post types just cover posts, pages and all custom post types, right? If I'm only having this issue with a category, I still have to reset the menu_order of the entire parent post type?
3. I see the menu_order filter in the Codex, but I thought this was only for top level menu order, not the order of actual posts?

Comment: This is a **SQL/PHPMyAdmin** question, *not* a **WordPress** question. (There are on-topic elements of this question; please revise to focus on the **WordPress-specific** elements of your issue).

Comment: The parts about correcting the jumbled menu order and about how the `menu_order` column in the `*_posts` table works is on topic, which is most of the question, even if the fix is a quick query via PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: If the answer is "use this SQL query", then the question is **off-topic**. But, the focus of the question can be changed, such that your **on-topic** answer applies. I'm hoping the OP will update the question accordingly.

Comment: Doesn't the fact that I'm asking about Wordpress-specific database structures make this a Wordpress question? I mean, I'm asking about table structure specific to Wordpress — something someone familiar with Wordpress would be able to best advise on. That being said, should I just adjust the title of this question?

Comment: @ChipBennett : _Asking_ for plugin recommendations is off-topic, but questions where the answer is "use this plugin" are not considered off-topic. The same rule should apply should it not?

Comment: Another issue is that you're essentially asking three different questions, as one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This piece of mySQL code should do the trick.  Go into PHPmyAdmin, click the SQL tab and paste this code:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET menu_order = 0 WHERE post_type = 'my_post_type';
```

This should set `menu_order` for all posts of the post type of your choice to 0.

Answer (score 2):

[`menu_order` is one of the columns in the `*_posts` table.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table%3a_wp_posts) In my dev database it only seems to be used for the `nav_menu_item` post type, but I haven't looked into it very carefully.

I am not sure about the connection to your categories. When I add a category, it is added to the menu as a `nav_menu_item`. Presumably that is how things work on your site too, unless someone has done something weird.

I don't think that altering that value will break anything. When I tested the menus just reordered but that is it. Make backups and test it on dummy data first.

Comment: `'menu_order'` is used by both the `nav_menu_item` post type, *and* the `page` post type - the latter, when returning `wp_page_menu()` or `wp_list_pages()` if the `'sort_column'` parameter is set to `'menu_order'`. I'm honestly not sure how *categories* are factoring into the OP's issue.